# Why are there no "general" accessor functions for tuples in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I know there is `fst` and `snd`, but why is there no "general" definition for such accessor functions using type classes? I would suggest something like

```
class Get1 p a | p -> a where
  get1 :: p -> a 

instance Get1 (a,b) a where
  get1 (x,_) = x 

instance Get1 (a,b,c) a where
  get1 (x,_,_) = x 

class Get2 p a | p -> a where
  get2 :: p -> a 

instance Get2 (a,b) b where
  get2 (_,x) = x 

instance Get2 (a,b,c) b where
  get2 (_,x,_) = x
```

Sure, you need some language extensions for this, but isn't this *much* more convenient like that? Especially you can add instances for your own types.

Comment: This and other tuple goodies are available in the [tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple) package.

Comment: The answer is probably "because nobody uses tuples very much". Certainly not large ones, anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing to note is that `fst` and `snd` only allow one to view into a 2-tuple. Generalizing them to other arities and operations quickly becomes painful. If you want to also, for instance, map on the first element of a tuple, you have to introduce another combinator (which, for the record, exists for 2-tuples as `Control.Arrow.first`). This quickly leads to an explosion in the number of combinators for high arity tuples.

That being said, `lens` provides some nice tools to working with tuples. [`Control.Lens.Tuple`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.8.7.3/doc/html/Control-Lens-Tuple.html) provides several index lenses `_1`, `_2`, etc. which allow access to the first, second, etc. elements of tuples up to arity 9.

For example,

```
>>> import Control.Lens
>>> let t = (1,2,3,5,6,7,2)
>>> t ^._1
1
>>> t & _1 .~ 'a'
('a',2,3,5,6,7,2)
>>> t & _1 +~ 41
(42,2,3,5,6,7,2)
>>> over _1 (+1) t
(2,2,3,5,6,7,2)
```

You may also be interested in the tuple instances in [`Control.Lens.At`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.8.7.3/doc/html/Control-Lens-At.html). Also, the `tuple-lenses` [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-lenses) provides  some more general lenses for examining multiple tuple entries at once.

Answer (score 3):

Such type classes give only coding (syntax) convenience, I don't see how to build generalized over tuple type tools upon them. If you are looking for tuple generalization, check [the discussion about heterogeneous vectors](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/19pspd/i_just_put_together_a_package_for_heterogenous/) on Reddit.

Also note, that for ordinary structures it is preferable to define your own ADTs and provide getters with sensible names then use tuples of high arity.

Edit: however, as is7s pointed in the comment, there is a number of packages on hackage which provide indexing functions for tuples of arbitrary length.

Comment: No, the package I referred to is not implemented using `TemplateHaskell`. The `Data.Tuple.Select` module is implemented in a similar manner to what the OP did.